# How to access service variable from delegated function (callback)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angularjs-service

I am using a service which gots a variable which needs to get updated by the service. But I can not reach the var in anonymus functions / delegated functions.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
      .module('yoTest')
      .service('mainService', mainService);

  /** @ngInject */
  function mainService($timeout) {
    this.counter = 1;
    this.updateCounter = function updateCounter() {
      this.counter++;
      $timeout(updateCounter, 500);
    }
    this.updateCounter();
  }
})();
```

If I reload the "updateCounter" via `$timeout` I'll get an error, why?

How to access it via timeout and delegate/callback?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is while calling function you just passed `updateCounter` function reference inside `$timeout` callback. Because of which when `$timeout` tries to evaluate that function, `this` belongs to `updateCounter` will be its own `this` rather than considering `this` of `mainService`. In such cases you have to explicitly pass current context by using `.bind(this)`

```
this.updateCounter = function updateCounter() {
  this.counter++;
  console.log(this.counter)
  $timeout(updateCounter.bind(this), 500);
}
```

[**PLuker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MJCZRL5UGIulqkPVm1Jo?p=info)

Same thing can be achievable in ES6 by using `Fat Arrow` function

```
$timeout(() => { updateCounter () }, 500);
```

Comment: helpful, but how can I update the controller/view binding?
http://plnkr.co/edit/V4dm0rYTk4sp187UuD2J

Comment: @n00n [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0zIgSRCVIuteqbKxcKqF?p=preview) could be a way of implementing the same

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to Pankaj's answer you can bind the current context to a variable and refer the properties and functions by using this variable.

```
function mainService($timeout) {
  var service = this;

  this.counter = 1;

  this.updateCounter = function updateCounter() {
    service.counter++;
    console.log(service.counter)
    $timeout(service.updateCounter, 500);
  }

  this.updateCounter();

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EuTiiP8HZUPulmJIX3IP